# Question about Gnu/Linux command line interface, with grep, ls, and cat

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, cat

Greetings Stack Exchange,

**My Goal**:Execute `ls` to search the entire directory structure and `grep` to search for `cats.py`. Use `cat` to read the file `cats.py`. I know that sounds like Gnu/Linux inception.

I currently am new to `bash` and not really familiar with Stack Exchange so forgive me if this formatted terribly.

I execute the following `ls -R -l -t -r | grep cats` this returns the following

```
rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2179 Mar 18 08:53 cats.py
```

I have tried to use cat to read the file returned above, but I am having issues with how to assign the placeholder for the results of the grep command this is what I have tried and the results.

```
ls -R -l -t -r | grep cats | cat cats.py
cat: cats.py: No such file or directory
```

I believe the issues is the way I am executing the cat function should this look something like :

```
ls -R -l -t -r | grep cats | cat '{}'
```

or

```
ls -R -l -t -r | grep cats && cat cats.py
```

Comment: You may need to study the linux shell some more, especially concerning the "CWD", ie. the Current Working Directory.  When you have found the file, you should specify the full path or put yourself in that directory with "cd", before executing the "cat" command.

Comment: Also, [you should not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `find` command. It can find the file, and run a command on it. `ls` has problems, especially if the `-l` option is given, as then you have a lot more data than you need (file-mode, date, owner,  ... ).

i.e. (substitute the bits in the «»)

`find «directory» -name '«file-name-glob-pattern»' -exec «command» {} \;`

e.g.

`find . -name 'cats.py' -exec cat {} \;`

Comment: Thank you for the information and the edit you Ladies and Gentlemen are the reason I enjoy learning new things. You answered the next question I was going to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The find command would be more appropriate:

```
find . -name 'cats.py' -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly exactly what I was trying to accomplish Thank you very much

Comment: Why not `-exec ... +` ? Should have the same output.

Comment: @pLumo why though? The `+` is to run fewer commands, but there's no benefit here. First because `cat` will print everything sequentially anyway and because we have no reason to expect multiple files.

Comment: @terdon in order to inform people about this feature. This feature is from 1989 and many people from the GNU universe don't know it yet as it has been ignored by `gfind` until recently.

Comment: Ah, that's my excuse: when I learned unix the feature wasn't there yet!

Comment: If there is only one cats.py it doesn't make a difference of course... But I don't really see that information from the question and then I rather call `cat` once. Habits ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `find -exec`, use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
cat **/cats.py
```

Optional: unset extglob option:

```
shopt -u extglob
```

---

Note, that this is similar to `-exec cat {} +` instead of `-exec cat {} \;`

The first runs:

```
cat file1 file2 file3
```

The latter runs:

```
cat file1
cat file2
cat file3
```

For this example, the output is the same but the first will run faster.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but seems to do what you requested.

```
cat `sudo ls -R -l -t -r | grep cats | awk '{print $9}'`

cat `sudo ls -R -l -t -r | grep `Local\ State` | awk '{print $9}'`
```